# Google Drive SDK thread safety

Tags: .net, thread-safety, google-drive-api

I want to use Google drive SDK in a multithreaded environment. Is the function `Files.Insert` in `DriveService` class thread safe? I can't find anything related to that in the documentation. I can't even find word **thread** there.

Does anybody know how is multithreading handled in Google SDK? Do I need to create separate `DriveService` object for each thread?

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing some performance testing on the Google Drive SDK for a winforms application that I am working on that uses it.  I saw this post and realized that I never thought to check on that issue, as I always assumed that the API was thread safe.  So I ran some tests.  I have been doing some performance testing on a file renaming method as follows:

```
    public static bool SetFileName(string gFileID, string filename, int attempt)
    {
        File sourcefile;
        File replacement = new File();
        bool save = false;
        replacement.Title = filename;
        replacement.Description = filename;
        try
        {
            FilesResource.PatchRequest request = DriveService.Files.Patch(replacement, gFileID);
            sourcefile = request.Fetch();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (attempt < 10)
            {
                return SetFileName(gFileID, filename, attempt + 1);
            }
            throw e;
        }
        bool result = sourcefile.Title == replacement.Title & sourcefile.Description == replacement.Description;
        if(!result && attempt<10)
            return SetFileName(gFileID, filename, attempt + 1);
        return result;
    }
```

I was running sequential tests to get error rates and execution times for this method.  When I read your post I decided to run the tests on background workers to see how the method worked in a multi-threaded environment.  In the example above, the DriveService object was instantiated as follows:

```
    private static DriveService DriveService
    {
        get
        {
            if (_service == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _service = new DriveService(Auth);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
            return _service;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, my DriveService object is instantiated once, so that with multiple background workers running simultaneously, all of them were using the same instance of DriveService.  I ran the test with 1000 simultaneous threads, and although it did generate some errors, those errors were all "(500) Internal Server Errors" returned from the google drive server.  It appeared that all file names were set properly, and all the threads completed without hanging.

However, on a separate performance test, I attempted to determine if there were significant performance issues with instantiating the DriveService each and every time it was needed.  So I modified my code as follows:

```
    private static DriveService DriveService
    {
        get
        {
            return new DriveService(Auth);
        }
    }
```

And I ran some performance tests again, this time looking to see if there was a significant difference in the time it took to run 100 simultaneous threads between a singleton DriveService instance and creating a new drive instance for each thread.  I did not see any significant difference in performance.  Although there were variations between runs, it appeared to me that those variations had everything to do with the server side processing time to run the PatchRequest, and almost nothing to do with whether you created a new instance of the DriveService when needed.

I know this is not definitive, but it looks to me like the Google Drive SDK is thread safe.  However, if it is not, it does not appear that there is any performance issues in treating it as though it is not thread safe.

I hope this helps.